# go program systematically crashing on semacquire issue after hours of execution

Tags: http, go

Here is an extract of my code:

```
func sendTo(url string, someDataPoints [] DataPoint) {
  ro := &grequests.RequestOptions{JSON: someDataPoints, InsecureSkipVerify: false}
  grequests.Post(url, ro)
  return
}

func forward(someDataPoints []DataPoint) int {
    endpoint := "https://example.org"
    go sendTo(endpoint, someDataPoints)
}
```

The function forward is called something like 100 times per second. The program works for thirty hour or so and ends up failing with the following error:

```
goroutine 265125012 [semacquire, 41 minutes]:
sync.runtime_notifyListWait(0xc4204be2d0, 0x1bb56b6)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:510 +0x10b
sync.(*Cond).Wait(0xc4204be2c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/cond.go:56 +0x80
net/http.(*http2ClientConn).awaitOpenSlotForRequest(0xc420d5e000, 0xc42c167000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:7528 +0x11d
net/http.(*http2ClientConn).roundTrip(0xc420d5e000, 0xc42c167000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:7336 +0x110
net/http.(*http2Transport).RoundTripOpt(0xc4200100f0, 0xc42c167000, 0xffffffffffffff00, 0x0, 0x40bac0, 0x705e50)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:6929 +0x150
net/http.(*http2Transport).RoundTrip(0xc4200100f0, 0xc42c167000, 0xc42c1a04c0, 0x0, 0xc42c1a0438)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:6891 +0x3a
net/http.http2noDialH2RoundTripper.RoundTrip(0xc4200100f0, 0xc42c167000, 0x7fff668abf02, 0x5, 0xc42016a088)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:991 +0x39
net/http.(*Transport).RoundTrip(0x8aa800, 0xc42c167000, 0x8aa800, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:380 +0xc36
net/http.send(0xc42c167000, 0x745660, 0x8aa800, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc44002b628, 0xb000000000411729, 0xc420d52b50, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:252 +0x185
net/http.(*Client).send(0x8afa20, 0xc42c167000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc44002b628, 0x0, 0x1, 0x698620)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:176 +0xfa
net/http.(*Client).Do(0x8afa20, 0xc42c167000, 0x7fff668abf02, 0x3a, 0xc42bcc5b80)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:615 +0x28d
github.com/levigross/grequests.buildRequest(0x705a0f, 0x4, 0x7fff668abf02, 0x3a, 0xc42bcc5b80, 0x8afa20, 0x8, 0x18, 0xc431e455a0)
    /go/src/github.com/levigross/grequests/request.go:194 +0x189
github.com/levigross/grequests.doRegularRequest(0x705a0f, 0x4, 0x7fff668abf02, 0x3a, 0xc42bcc5b80, 0x690380, 0x1, 0xc431e455a0)
    /go/src/github.com/levigross/grequests/request.go:136 +0x6f
github.com/levigross/grequests.Post(0x7fff668abf02, 0x3a, 0xc42bcc5b80, 0xc431e455a0, 0x4, 0xc42c1703c0)
    /go/src/github.com/levigross/grequests/base.go:41 +0x54
main.sendTo(0x7fff668abf02, 0x3a, 0xc42bcd33b0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/SomeCompany/SomeProduct/cmd/SomeCli/main.go:66 +0xdd
created by main.forward
    /go/src/github.com/SomeCompany/SomeProduct/cmd/SomeCli/main.go:80 +0xc8
```

What could explain this issue?

Comment: This particular goroutine is stuck waiting for available HTTP2 stream to send a request over. When a Go program crashes and dumps the state of all goroutines - it's probably a very long list in your case. After 30h you might have hundred of thousand of goroutines opened and you might be running out of file descriptors for all the connections that you have opened. Might be useful to use something like https://github.com/google/pprof to investigate a bit more.

Comment: @ohe, are you certain that’s all that is printed out? Its not showing the panic or fatal error, and there’s no situation where go runtime just prints out a random waiting goroutine stack.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem to have an actual error displayed in there. Just a stack trace. I'm not sure why.

What I do see is that you appear to just launch goroutines without any limit. What does your program do if it cannot forward and complete `sendTo` requests faster than they arrive?

I think that at some point Go will run out of memory for goroutine stacks, or something else will overflow. I'd expect some sort of "out of memory" error, but I don't see one there.

Nevertheless, that is my best guess: some sort of resource exhaustion caused by creating more goroutines than are finishing.

Comment: can you suggest a solution?

Comment: @PraveenRaj: I might use a buffered channel to process requests one at a time. Once it reaches the buffer limit it cannot push more into the channel. Or I might use an unbuffered channel and create `N` goroutines reading it, where `N` is however many I want to run at the same time.